# Need explanation of this php code $variable = array();

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse me for possibly stupid question, but need to understand how the code works. Searched google and no understandable answer

Here is code:

```
$data = array_merge($one,$two);
$sql = "INSERT INTO msql_table (One, Two) VALUES ";
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['one'] as $i => $one) {
    $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)';
    $insertData[] = $one;
    $insertData[] = $_POST['two'][$i];
}
if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
    $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($insertData);
}
```

Can not understand this code:

```
$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();
```

Usual code would be `"INSERT INTO msql_table (One, Two) VALUES (?, ?)";`

I understand that `VALUES` are `$insertQuery = array();` and `array()` will be defined latter.... but big mess in my head.

May be some link with information about the code (explanation of code)? Want to understand what these two lines do

Comment: hopefully this doesn't live on the internet, cause if someone finds it. sql injection for the win.  but basically it intializes them to empty array and then `$insertData[] = ` just pushes the RHS into the array, and then they join the mess together at the end.

Comment: It's missing a few lines, but this code is using PDO. Using $stmt->execute($insertData) will escape the variables.

Comment: @tadman & @doon: this code is... actually using prepared statements and parameters correctly. There is no arbitrary data anywhere in the query string, only enough `?` placeholders to perform an arbitrary amount of inserts in 1 query....

Comment: Thanks for link. Actually I took one example changed it (code did not worked as expected), then received advice and get the code work as expected. Main aim now is to fully understand how foreach works. For sql injections actually until now supposed that prepared statement escapes by itself. Latter will study. Now head is full with information and need to understand foreach and the code in the example

Comment: It does look rather muddled, but @Wrikken is right that it has placeholders in there. PDO really needs a better way of doing this that doesn't involve so much bashing around. I've retracted my earlier warning.

Comment: @user2360838: you are correct in that the prepared statement does NOT make you vulnerable to injection attacks contrary to what these other guys claim. What happens in the `foreach()` loop is that 2 placeholders are added to an array `(?,?)`, and 2 values are added to the data array. The resulting query string (`INSERT .. INTO .. VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?)` can then insert more then 1 record in one query, optimizing insert speed / index updating.

Comment: by the way... why down votes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two lines just initialize the variable, and creates an empty array. This way, when the data is inserted into the array later, PHP won't complain (depending on error_reporting) that the variable doesn't exist.

Here's a link about the http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: So $insertQuery = array(); creates empty array, then $insertQuery[] = '(?, ?)'; as if first ? binds with array $insertData[] = $one; and the second ? binds with array $insertData[] = $_POST['two'][$i]; Or I am wrong in my thoughts?

Comment: `$array[] = $value` is PHP shorthand syntax for `array_push($array, $value)`

Comment: Actually, at that point, insertQuery and insertData have nothing to do with each other, but once PDO executes the query, yes, the first ? will be $one, and the second ? will be  $_POST['two'][$i] in that sub-array.